# How can I create a new Git configuration file?

Tags: macos, github

I want to configure Git, but I deleted my configuration file before (a big mistake). It shows me

> No such file or directory

when I put in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
$ git config global user.name "a"
error: key does not contain a section: global
$ ~/.gitconfig
-bash:/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add dashes to `global`:

```
git config --global user.name "a"
```

Without the dashes `global` is getting interpreted as a section, but that's not valid. You want the [`--global` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---global).

The file doesn't need to exist before you run this command. Git will create it if it's not there.

Comment: Sorry, actually I add dashes to global. I put wrong description.error: could not lock config file /usr/.gitconfig: No such file or directory

Comment: That's a completely different issue and a completely different question. Your original question showed an error that would be caused by forgetting the dashes. That's the question I answered. Clarifying your question after asking it is fine, but please avoid completely changing it (especially after it's been voted on and received answers).

Comment: @JieZou, do you literally mean `/usr/.gitconfig`? Or `/home/user/your_username/.gitconfig`?

Comment: It exist indeed.Thank you.